# Unable to run an (Py)OpenGL application via SSH - failed to load driver swrast

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I'm working on an OpenGL application written in Python, using PyOpenGL. It runs well on my Mac and also on other Linux system, however if I run it on our remote cluster via SSH and X-forwarding, I get the error (also when running glxinfo):

```
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /whatever/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
OpenGL Version: 1.4 (2.1 NVIDIA-10.0.31 310.90.10.05b12)
```

I'm wondering why OpenGL tries to load the swrast driver (this is the software fallback right?), since I thought it would forward it to my machine, so it handles the driver stuff. I'm probably wrong…

Comment: Workaround: `LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=yes`

Comment: Well, with this workaround I get ~0.1fps.